# Create Error object for Stripe::Error (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, stripe-payments, standard-error

I am able to create standard errors as below...

```
StandardError.new("No such customer: invalid-id")
```

However, I would like to know how to create specific errors, specifically Stripe errors...

https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/382ae0b45d848304f7c1739696f33458c86bee4f/lib/stripe/errors.rb#L99

```
Stripe::RateLimitError
Stripe::InvalidRequestError
Stripe::AuthenticationError
Stripe::InvalidRequestError
Stripe::StripeError
```

What is the best way to create these errors?  Which I use to pass to the my mock Api library.  I found this...

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/master/test/stripe/errors_test.rb

I have tried...
`Stripe::InvalidRequestError.new('this is a test')`
, but I get a ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)).

What is the required second argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the latest method definitions for Stripe Errors here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/ec91de6849f34d8d6701a6e91a1b2ee0d50c21ea/lib/stripe/errors.rb

Here is the method definition for `Stripe::InvalidRequestError`

```
class InvalidRequestError < StripeError
  attr_accessor :param

  def initialize(message, param, http_status: nil, http_body: nil,
                 json_body: nil, http_headers: nil, code: nil)
    super(message, http_status: http_status, http_body: http_body,
                   json_body: json_body, http_headers: http_headers,
                   code: code)
    @param = param
  end
end
```

So, in answer to your question, the second argument is the `param` argument. 
Generally, this seems to represent a stripe resource.

For example, if I wanted to create an InvalidRequestError having tried to do something related to the `Stripe::Plan` class, I would use the following code:

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError.new('No such plan: test_plan', 'plan')
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You can raise it by making some kind of invalid request, e.g. ```retrieve``` or ```delete``` an object that doesn't exist. You could also raise it forcefully by writing ```raise Stripe::InvalidRequestError.new('No such plan: test_plan', 'plan')```

Comment: How can I raise it manually ? Without making an invalid request?

Comment: just edited my post a bit after you made the last comment :)